# Position objects or entities as relationships

Tags: architecture, plantuml

I am trying to draw some diagrams mimicking examples at [awslabs/aws-icons-for-plantuml](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-icons-for-plantuml) . There are two issues I am facing (please excuse the loose terminologies):

- How to add objects on top of another object/entity?
- How to add objects/entities between entities in place of notes or comments?

In the diagram below,

a) I would like to add `Role1` on top of vpc or ec2 instance or any boundary to highlight that only r1 can access this resource.

b) I would like to add `Role2` entity between EC2 and Queue Service. This is to highlight that r2 has access to SNS message between (not shown).

Code:

```
@startuml VPC
!define AWSPuml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/aws-icons-for-plantuml/v13.1/dist
!include AWSPuml/AWSCommon.puml
!include AWSPuml/AWSSimplified.puml
!include AWSPuml/Compute/EC2.puml
!include AWSPuml/Compute/EC2Instance.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/AWSCloud.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/VPC.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/AvailabilityZone.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/PublicSubnet.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/PrivateSubnet.puml
!include AWSPuml/NetworkingContentDelivery/VPCNATGateway.puml
!include AWSPuml/SecurityIdentityCompliance/IdentityAccessManagementRole.puml
!include AWSPuml/ApplicationIntegration/SimpleQueueService.puml

hide stereotype
skinparam linetype ortho
AWSCloudGroup(cloud) {

  VPCGroup(vpc) {

    AvailabilityZoneGroup(az_1, "\tAvailability Zone 1\t") {
      PublicSubnetGroup(az_1_public, "Public subnet") {
        VPCNATGateway(az_1_nat_gateway, "NAT gateway", "") #Transparent
      }
      PrivateSubnetGroup(az_1_private, "Private subnet") {
        EC2Instance(az_1_ec2_1, "Instance", "") #Transparent
      }

  IdentityAccessManagementRole("r1", "Role1", " ")
  IdentityAccessManagementRole("r2", "Role2", " ")

  SimpleQueueService("sqs", "Queue Service", " ")

    az_1_ec2_1 .u.> az_1_nat_gateway
    az_1_ec2_1 --> sqs:[$r1]
    }

  }
}
@enduml
```

Corresponding diagram:

[image]

I would like the roles to be placed at positions shown by arrowhead:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "on top of." It might be better if you can edit an image (by hand, or with annotations) to show how you want things positioned.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator updated image. Place `Role1` and `Role2` be at the end of arrow (on top of availability zone and in between Instance and Queue Service). Hope that clarifies the problem.

Comment: That rather looks like powerpoint, not UML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy is to use the `<img:...>` inside of labels or names of elements. I found some insight to make your role icons smaller in an [issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-icons-for-plantuml/issues/43#issuecomment-1140590872) on the aws-icons-for-plantuml repo. You may feel like adjusting the `{scale=..}` values.

To position Role2, I made a hidden rectangle above `az_1` whose name is the image wrapped with the role name in bold. Because it's a rectangle name, the font is bigger than the label used on an association (as in Role1). These are "hacks" and so as you can see they're far from perfect.

```
@startuml VPC
!define AWSPuml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/aws-icons-for-plantuml/v13.1/dist
!include AWSPuml/AWSCommon.puml
!include AWSPuml/AWSSimplified.puml
!include AWSPuml/Compute/EC2.puml
!include AWSPuml/Compute/EC2Instance.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/AWSCloud.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/VPC.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/AvailabilityZone.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/PublicSubnet.puml
!include AWSPuml/Groups/PrivateSubnet.puml
!include AWSPuml/NetworkingContentDelivery/VPCNATGateway.puml
!include AWSPuml/SecurityIdentityCompliance/IdentityAccessManagementRole.puml
!include AWSPuml/ApplicationIntegration/SimpleQueueService.puml

skinparam Rectangle<<hidden>> {
    BackgroundColor transparent
    BorderColor transparent
}

hide stereotype
skinparam linetype ortho
AWSCloudGroup(cloud) {

  VPCGroup(vpc) {

    'IdentityAccessManagementRole("r1", "Role1", " ")
    rectangle "<img:AWSPuml/SecurityIdentityCompliance/IdentityAccessManagementRole.png{scale=0.4}>\n<b>Role1</b>" as r1  <<hidden>>
    AvailabilityZoneGroup(az_1, "\tAvailability Zone 1\t") {
        PublicSubnetGroup(az_1_public, "Public subnet") {
            VPCNATGateway(az_1_nat_gateway, "NAT gateway", "") #Transparent
        }
        PrivateSubnetGroup(az_1_private, "Private subnet") {
            EC2Instance(az_1_ec2_1, "Instance", "") #Transparent
        }

        SimpleQueueService("sqs", "Queue Service", " ")

        az_1_ec2_1 .u.> az_1_nat_gateway
        'IdentityAccessManagementRole("r1", "Role1", " ")
        az_1_ec2_1 --> sqs:"<img:AWSPuml/SecurityIdentityCompliance/IdentityAccessManagementRole.png{scale=0.4}>  \n<b>Role2  </b>"
    }

    az_1 -[hidden]up- r1 

  }
}
@enduml
```

Here's a PNG of that:

[image: PNG]

Comment: Awesome, wasn't aware of the `<img:...>` construct. This works as expected, thanks!